# What is my exponential potential?

Tags: code-golf, math, number

We'll define the ***N***-exponential potential of a positive integer **M** as the count of prefixes of **M<sup>N</sup>** that are perfect **N**-powers.

The prefixes of an integer are all the contiguous subsequences of digits that start with the first one, interpreted as numbers in base 10. For example, the prefixes of **2744** are **2**, **27**, **274** and **2744**.

A prefix **P** is a perfect **N**-power if there exists an integer **K** such that **K<sup>N</sup> = P**. For example, **81** is a perfect **4**-power because **3<sup>4</sup> = 81**.

---

Given two strictly positive integers **M** and **N**, compute the **N**-exponential potential of **M** according to the definition above.

For instance, the **2**-exponential potential of **13** is **3** because **13<sup>2</sup>** is **169**, and **1**, **16** and **169** are all perfect squares.

### Test cases

Naturally, the outputs will nearly always be pretty small because powers are... well... exponentially growing functions and having multiple perfect-power prefixes is rather rare.

```
M, N     -> Output

8499, 2  -> 1
4,    10 -> 2
5,    9  -> 2
6,    9  -> 2
13,   2  -> 3
```

Comment: hello, how the output of : ( 4, 10 ) is 2  and not 1?   because 4 power 10 is 1048576, 1 is a perfect power but not 10

Comment: @AliISSA Hi, The output for `4, 10` is **2**, because **1** is a perfect 10-power and **1048576** is also a perfect 10-power (while **10**, **104**, **1048**, **10485** and **104857** are not). Thus, there are 2 valid prefixes, so the output is 2.

Answer (score 10):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
{^a₀.&b~b^}ᶜ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vzou8VFTg55aUl1SXO3DbXP@/482NAACHaPY/1EA)

### Explanation

```
{^a₀.&b~b^}ᶜ
{         }ᶜ  Count the number of ways the following can succeed:
  a₀            A prefix of
 ^                the first {input} to the power of the second {input}
    .&          produces the same output with the same input as
       ~b         any number
         ^        to the power of
      b           all inputs but the first (i.e. the second input)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
*DḌƤÆE%Ḅċ0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/L5eGOnmNLDre5qj7c0XKk2@C/tdLh5fqPmta4//8fbWFiaamjYBSroxBtoqNgaABimOooWIJoMyhtaAxSAQA)

#### How it works

```
*DḌƤÆE%Ḅċ0  Main link. Left argument: m. Right argument: n.

*           Compute m**n.
 D          Generate its decimal digits.
  ḌƤ        Convert prefixes back to integers.
    ÆE      Get the exponents of each prefix's prime factorization.
      %     Take all exponents modulo n.
            For a perfect n-th power, all moduli will be 0.
       Ḅ    Convert from binary to integer, mapping (only) arrays of 0's to 0.
        ċ0  Count the zeroes.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 56 bytes

```hs
0%n=0
x%n=sum[1|t<-[1..x],t^n==x]+div x 10%n
m#n=(m^n)%n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxNCoMwEAXgfU4xYIWEjuL4UyiYk4QIkQqVmlCatGTh3dPUbubjwXtzN/6xbFtKTelkw2K@/m0V7WGsFNV11BgmJ2XU59v6gQiUi8wWTnI7OVG6FBYfPEhQvEdqBAIf8CoA@SWTE3XYHiL9aLu/hIPQjFmzujx@vlYX4ATKFPPODc5irI7HOn0B)

Extracts the prefixes arithmetically by repeated `\x->div x 10`. I tried expressing the last line point-free but didn't find a shorter expression.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
mηÓ¹%O0¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/99z2w5MP7VT1Nzi06P9/Iy5DYwA)

Uses Dennis's Jelly 10-byte algorithm. Inputs are in reversed order.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 38 bytes

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
/ /;$_=grep/^${\++$n**$'}/,($`**$')x$`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQd9aJd42vSi1QD9OpTpGW1slT0tLRb1WX0dDJQHE0qxQSfj/39BYwehffkFJZn5e8X/dAgA)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 73 bytes

```
m#n=sum[1|c<-scanl(\s c->s++[c])"0"$show$m^n,any(==read c)$map(^n)[1..m]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcdLCsIwEADQvacYmiwS@qFRl6YXiSkMaaHFzLR0FBG8e9z6dm9Becw5l0KKvbwouG@6tZKQs7kLpHaQug4p2qqvtCzbW9PIDfLHeH/MOEGymnA3I9vguo5iLIQrg4dpOwHsx8pP0HBVrv@ru6hz@QE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 105 bytes

```java
m->n->{int c=1,k=m;for(;--k>0;)if((""+(int)Math.pow(m,n)).matches((int)Math.pow(k,n)+".*"))c++;return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9NS8NAEIbv/RVDTrtNszRaxbAmIIjgoad6Ew/rNmk3yX6QnVRKyW@PS/VgQLCeZphnnuGdWhxEYl1p6m2TjUo72yHUYch6VC2reiNRWcPmfCZb4T2shTJwmgG4/r1VEjwKDOVg1RZ0YGSDnTK71zcQ3c7T8yrAs8Gn71P3jzaY5Yv9MSugykedFCYpTsogyDxdNLnmle0IT5KmWHKqKkKiKCaB07XAPXP2g@iFoZRpgXJfejJlTWBxxOYRpTKOeVdi3xmQfBj5OdPm6LHUzPbIXIiMrSEVE861R3K3yjL61T/4kJNcUfqntJoY6fIC5WaiZBcYt/820uvfPhlmw/gJ)

### Credits

- -1 byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

Comment: `.startsWith(""+(int)Math.pow(k,n))` can be `.matches((int)Math.pow(k,n)+".*")` for -1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 40 bytes

```perl6
{1+(^$^m X**$^n).grep({$m**$n~~/^$^p/})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2lBbI04lLlchQktLJS5PUy@9KLVAo1olF8jNq6vTB8oV6Ndq1v635ipOBOnRqFGJ11RIyy/i4tSwMLG01FEw0tQBsk10FAwNwCxTHQVLMMMMxjA0Bqv6DwA)

Comment: If you assign a Callable to a `&foo` variable you can call it as you would a subroutine `foo( 'bar' )` or `foo 'bar'` no need to include `&`. I mean you didn't write it as `&say(&f(|$_))` (`say` is not special in any way)

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills I only use Perl 6 for code golf and still have a lot to learn, so thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
*DḌƤ*İ}ær⁵%1¬S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//KkThuIzGpCrEsH3DpnLigbUlMcKsU////zX/OQ) or see the **[test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/L5eGOnmNLtI5sqD28rOhR41ZVw0Nrgv8f3XNoq7XS4eX6j5rWuP//b2FiaamjYKKjYKqjYKajYGj83whIGugoWIKREQA)**

### How it works

```
*DḌƤ*İ}ær⁵%1¬S - Main link. Arguments: n, m (integers)  e.g. 13, 2
*              - Power. Raise x to the power y               169
 D             - Convert to a list of digits                 [1 6 9]
   Ƥ           - Convert each Ƥrefix
  Ḍ            - Back to an integer                          [1 16 169]
     İ         - Calculate the İnverse of
      }        - The right argument                          0.5
    *          - Raise each element to that power            [1 4 13]
       ær⁵     - Round each to 10 ** -10                     [1 4 13]
               - to remove precision errors
          %1   - Take the decimal part of each               [0 0 0]
            ¬  - Logical NOT each                            [1 1 1]
             S - Sum                                         3
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>83</s> <s>71</s> 70 bytes

```python
n,m=input();s=n**m;k=0
while s:k+=round(s**(1./m))**m==s;s/=10
print k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU1LDoIwFNz3FG9Hiw0/0QikS9y68QIKTWgqbfNaopy@QnQzM5nMx61hsqaKgx2lSJIkGj4LZdwSKOu8MGk6d1oU5D2plwTf6oNAu5iR@jSlZZbPjG0RIXznc1EWxKEyAXTcpjIfUDnK/t07LrIlAAHXnQDkRw6w/5JdD9IF6G/XHtHiL/BE@dAkXuqm4VCRmsN2cOLQkPMO5XFzvw)

Thx for 1 from ovs.

Comment: @ovs: d'oh! been coding too much javascript lately... was thinking I'd need `math.round()` lol

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 31 bytes

```apl
{+/o=⌊o←(÷⍵)*⍨10⊥¨,\10⊥⍣¯1⊢⍺*⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqbX2NRz1dto@6FmlqHN7@qHerptaj3hWGBo@6lh5aoRMDZjzqXXxovSFQyaPeXUDZrbX//1uYWFoqpCkYcZkASUMDLlMgZcllBiYNjUEyAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 83 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
m#n=sum[1|x<-read<$>(tail$inits$show(m^n)),x`elem`((^n)<$>[1..m])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc1NC4JAEAbgc/srxo@DQknbFwnaIboVeaibFC644NLuKu5KBv532@xSRHMYZnjeYQqibpTzvmeiKmsNO6JJcGBKI@HIWDUixV0bTWpK8sjdeJow7jLJtHJVUd49cZW@P24zyqnIPM9sJpXiIBAX/9K3kJlUw/MtzeABHbQQx2YwFUPV6JOuDxLsZG@jEbyrg1IXtL4zRb8yx@QMyd6yLBshQZg0mJfodbFehCE4MIPPZ3igxas5gKefNBto@aYQfmn1n/B8oO9fc9Q/AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 60 bytes

```ruby
->m,n{c=1;s=m**n;c+=(0..m).count{|j|j**n==s}while 0<s/=10;c}
```

a lot of it is to deal with floating point errors

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7RDoIgFIDhe5/i3FVGpGktNXoR50Uhpi7BKaya@uyGWnOrGwbff3ZGpa6vPiH95lwg3lBiBzUpTJMHdE2WFsbFClOhuGzavM21E1J3jzS7M7BO9ZbYVkC7PjQAwqPreYBgB/qwIzSQCzC@rMEn2k/kwUyHf7KdkcZdTmREmF1oCrGAVv8SiVbPlFXGJSwyXirpDxsWA0KoB6I538QUvzn56exZMipZ7E9dyRrE52IwHvdv)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 89 bytes

```
m,n->1+(1..m-1).count{"${Math.pow(m+0.0,n)}".startsWith("${Math.pow(it+0.0,n).toInt()}")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY49D4IwEIZ3fsXFOLShNNSvCIlMLg5ODs7VCDTSK4EDB8Jvxw6aGMMlN7zPPXlzT0eVwSnvEKw2yHrd6KYAv20KF2oMFhyGAPzUPlCFLGf7TZIIWMmY87/LRoCKZ/hWQDKDd/NYrb/tYxD0uoI8ZTY9IQlMj667VQ8eZT4ehskKjDIVMiWljRSXd9chDYvlcNZUytq9mA39QwL5uJAt6Ybaq6GS/RqGPook51uZV/k4jdMb)

In the test cases, passed in n as double values (2.0, 10.0, 9.0) so that I don't have to convert to double when calling Math.pow().

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
*DḌƤœ&*€L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/L5eGOnmNLjk5W03rUtMbn////pv8tAQ)